# Visual Studio starting the wrong project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a solution with 5 projects.
When I set a project to be the startup-project and hit the debug button, one of the other prjects is started. Is that a bug?
Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Visual Studio by default will start *all* web projects in your solution.  Is it possible that other projects are staring *in addition* to the one you intend?

Answer (score 9):

If your projects are web applications, try assigning different Ports to Project Urls. It can be done in Project / Properties / Web / Project URL. My Visual Studio often runs the wrong project if they have the same url.

Comment: This is the only solution that works if you have multiple web applications that are for some reason defaulted to the same port in IIS Express. Thanks!

Comment: This solution worked for me. I had a WebAPI project that I duplicated. Regardless of the project I started the original is the only one that would open until I did this.

Answer (score 8):

I did not want to change the application root url so I did this which worked well.

Go to **Project / Properties / Web / Project URL**, and click the <kbd>Create Virtual Directory</kbd> button.  It will fix which version of your app is being used in IISExpress.

(I have several different branches that I use and this is a simple fix so I can use the same port for each... then my browser history still works.)

Answer (score 2):

I was having the exact same problem with VS2022. I can select any project from the "Startup Projects" drop down shown to the left of the debug button (green triangle, shortcut F5). But when pressing F5 a different (always the same!) project is started.

It turned out that ReSharper was interfering. Apparently, R# has its own startup configuration. Open view "Build & Run" offered by R#. At the very top you see a drop down, with the project that always starts being selected. Choose the first entry (ending with `(VS Startup)`) instead.

Now F5 will again start the project configured in the VS startup project configuration.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check the properties of the Solution and make sure that one project is selected and that multiple projects are not selected in the startup project selection.

Comment: Only one project is marked as startup project. Still another project is launched...

Answer (score 1):

In VS 2010, you can right-click a project and select "Set as start up project". However, you can also right click the solution and select properties. In the dialog there are options for "Single startup project" and "Multiple startup projects". Are you sure "Multiple..." isn't selected here?