# Visual Studio 2013 Not Running Correct Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have a multiple project solution in Visual Studio 2013.  I'm not sure what caused it, but now when I click run, it runs a different project from the one I currently have set as the StartUp project.  The project I'm trying to run and the project visual studio runs instead both work and CAN run.  The problem occured when I booted up Visual Studio 2013 today I don't believe much has change since I last ran the project either, as I ran it yesterday.

I've tried closing and opening Visual Studio 2013, resetting my project as the StartUp project, right-clicking -> Debug -> Start new instance.  All these did not fix the problem though.

SOLUTION: Rebooting my machine fixed the problem, I have no idea...

Comment: Are these web projects? Are these SO questions any help? _[Visual Studio starting the wrong project](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12733838/4265041)_ or _[Visual Studio 2012 Launches Wrong Project For Debugging](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20479949/4265041)_

Comment: Have you tried to change `Solution Configuration` and(or) `Solution Platform` (either in project properties or on the `Standard` tool panel)?

Comment: @StevenRands I feel dumb, but rebooting my machine made it work again.  Oh Windows